# How to filter only subjects observed more than once in panel data with R?

Tags: r, dplyr, panel, missing-data

I am analyzing panel data with R now, and the data format is as follows.

```
pid wave edu marri rela age  apt sido dongy urban stat1 stat2 exer dep3 bmi  mmse
1 3122    1   2  <NA>   NA  NA <NA>   NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
2 3122    1  NA     1   NA  NA <NA>   NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
3 3122    1  NA  <NA>    3  NA <NA>   NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
4 3122    1  NA  <NA>   NA  71 <NA>   NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
5 3122    1  NA  <NA>   NA  NA    1   NA  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
6 3122    1  NA  <NA>   NA  NA <NA>   11  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA <NA>
```

The data are repeated measurements, and there are many missing values. If only the observed values are left at every year, the loss of the number is large, so I want to select and analyze **only subjects who have been measured more than once among the 'mmse' variables**.

I tried to check the change of the variable of interest through the following code, but it didn't work.

```
df %>%
  arrange(pid, wave) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>%
  mutate(
    mmse_change = mmse - lag(mmse),
    mmse_increase = mmse_change > 0,
    mmse_decrease = mmse_change < 0
  )
```

I need the above object to analyze the baseline characteristic. How can I extract subjects with this condition?

Answer (score 1):

We could do something like this:

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(mmse)) %>%   # just keep rows with non-NA in mmse
  count(pid) %>%             # count how many observations per pid
  filter(n > 1) %>%          # keep those pid's appearing more than once
  select(pid) %>%            # just keep the pid column
  left_join(df)              # get `df` for just those pid's
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without join is to `group_by(pid)` and then `filter` all groups where `max(row_number()) > 1`.

Below I changed your initial data so that it can be used for this problem (your original data has only `NA`s in `mmse` and please put your data in reproducible code next).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# initial data slightly changed:
df <- tribble(~pid, ~wave, ~edu, ~marri, ~rela, ~age, ~apt, ~sido, ~dongy, ~urban, ~stat1, ~stat2, ~exer, ~dep3, ~bmi,  ~mmse,
3122 ,   1,   2,  NA,   NA,  NA, NA,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, 1,
3122 ,   1,  NA,   1,   NA,  NA, NA,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA,
3122 ,   1,  NA,  NA,    3,  NA, NA,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, 2,
3122 ,   1,  NA,  NA,   NA,  71, NA,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA,
3122 ,   1,  NA,  NA,   NA,  NA,  1,   NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, 3,
3124 ,   1,  NA,  NA,   NA,  NA, NA,   11,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA,  NA, 5)

df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(mmse)) %>%
  group_by(pid) %>% 
  filter(max(row_number()) > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 x 16
#>     pid  wave   edu marri  rela   age   apt  sido dongy urban stat1 stat2 exer 
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1  3122     1     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#> 2  3122     1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#> 3  3122     1    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
#> # ... with 3 more variables: dep3 <lgl>, bmi <lgl>, mmse <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>